# Event handling and 'this' in Sencha Touch

Tags: event-handling, controller, this, sencha-touch

```
app.controllers.test = new Ext.Controller({
    someMethod: function(button, event) {
        // prints 'undefined', as this == button, not test
        console.log(typeof(this.someMethod));
    }
});
```

*someMethod* is called when the button is pressed:

```
handler: app.controllers.test.someMethod
```

Are there any workarounds? What are the best practices here?

I used to use the *bind* method of Prototype when developing for webOS, but don't know how to go about this in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found an awesome video that answers my question. Here:
http://vimeo.com/17414405